# How to create tableLayout with different number of columns in each row

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I used relative layout  view and every row i create new relative view for 2 and 3 column i try to make it in one tablelayout but there is problem in the case of column i can't be  create in same one tablelayout with 2 column in one row and another with 3 column how can i create it can anyone explain me with example plz
 my code is:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <include layout="@layout/navactionbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rotaract KNE"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@color/navheadtxt"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bodmen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Board Of Directory"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/table1">
            <TableRow>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/preimg"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_app"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/secimg"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_app"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/table2">
            <TableRow>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ppimg"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_app"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/tre_intimg"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_app"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/sgtatarmimg"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_app"

                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout3">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/table3">
            <TableRow>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/clubeimg"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_app"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/communitiyimg"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_app"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ppdimg"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_app"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure but no need to use relative layout as the outsider layout just add a table layout then add table rows then you can customize it the way you want